# php heading while in loop questions

Tags: php

I using a loop for questions which I've created for my product.

I need to put headings after every 4 questions. maybe use a table? I'm not sure of what would be the quickest way of doing it.

4 headings are:

- Marketing
- Product
- Usability
- Customer Service

Answer (score 3):

```
if($i % 4 == 0){
   //Echo your heading
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

See: Modulus

Edit: Now that you've added the 4 different headings - the best solution is to make the questions array multi-dimensional.

```
 $questions = [
      ['Marketing'] = [
           "Question 1 - This is question 1",
           "Question 2 - This is question 2",
           //etc
      ],
      //etc
  ];
```

And then loop through the headings, then loop through the questions within them. This solution also allows you to have different numbers of questions per section.

Also, use foreach. It's just cleaner.

```
$questionNumber = 1;
foreach($questions AS $heading => $sectionQuestions){
{
    echo "<h1>{$heading}</h1>";
    foreach(sectionQuestions AS $question)
    {
        echo $question;
        for ($radio = 6; $radio > 0; $radio--) //Weird, but whatever.
        {
            echo '<input type="radio" name="question[' . $questionNumber  . ']" value="' . $radio . '">' . $radio;
        }
        echo '<br>';
    }
    $questionNumber++;
}
```

Comment: hi, I keep getting this error :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
heres my code
   $questions = [
      ['Marketing'] = [
  "Question 1 - This is question 1",
  "Question 2 - This is question 2",
  "Question 3 - This is question 3",
  "Question 4 - This is question 4",

      ],
            ['Advertisement'] = [
  "Question 5 - This is question 5",
  "Question 6 - This is question 6",
  "Question 7 - This is question 7",
  "Question 8 - This is question 8",
  ];

Comment: You may be on an older version of PHP which does not support the new array syntax.

Comment: any alternatives please?

Comment: Use the normal array syntax.

Comment: Hi @Jessica. Sorry to mention civility again, but I do take the view that it is important here. Your answer was a good one - it's best to leave a conversation if it isn't going anywhere or excessive help is being requested. I'll vote to put the question on hold, I think.

Comment: @halfer I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. I was not rude at all to anyone here, and this question was not on hold when I answered it. If you're going to talk about civility, your comment seems pretty rude to me.

Comment: Hi @Jessica. My comments are intended to be constructive, I assure you - you are welcome to contact me via my blog/about page if you wish. Your comment was deleted earlier today by a moderator, who agreed with my flag. If memory serves correctly, you said something like "Jesus! You have had enough hand-holding now". I do appreciate that excessive requests for help are frustrating, though `:)`

Comment: I had absolutely no idea that any of that even happened, probably because this was TEN DAYS AGO. Are you stalking me or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($questions); $i++){
    if($i%4==0 && $i!=0){
        echo '<h2>This is heading</h2>';
    }
    echo $questions[$i] . '<br>';

    for ($radio = 6; $radio > 0; $radio--)
    {
       echo '<input type="radio" name="question[' . $i . ']" value="' . $radio . '">' . $radio;
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```